# Adding custom shoulda matchers to TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, shoulda

After using shoulda it is very clear that shoulda no longer uses macros (They are all deprecated for the preferred matchers) For example:

```
should_allow_custom_test
```

is **deprecated** for the following:

```
should allow_custom_test
```

However all the documentation I can find is for the former macro setup by placing them in the `shoulda_macros` directory. I thought the same could be accomplished with a custom **matcher** but shoulda can not find it them.

My matcher I'm using is at http://gist.github.com/613522

How do I include custom **matchers** into my `TestCase`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delving into active_record.rb, looks like the matchers are directly required into Test::Unit::TestCase
I think your gist pulls it into ActiveSupport::TestCase - not sure if that'd help... but might be worth a try.

From active_record.rb:

```
module Test # :nodoc: all
  module Unit
    class TestCase
      include Shoulda::ActiveRecord::Helpers
      include Shoulda::ActiveRecord::Matchers
      include Shoulda::ActiveRecord::Assertions
      extend Shoulda::ActiveRecord::Macros
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks that might actually be the case. I gave up a while ago and opted for custom macros as that is the only examples google can find these days. I will have to try matchers again some time.